# Possible to modify action in each iteration of awk? Please

Tags: bash, awk

Each line of my input file has format

```
[IDNum FirstName LastName test1Score test2Score test3Score......]
```

I need to print the test averages in the following format:

```
Test1: test1Avg  
Test2: test2Avg  
Test3: test3Avg  
.  
.  
.
```

I'm struggling immensely to get the test averages to be unique (not all the first test's avg)

I'm running this awk statement, but it prints out (it's obvious why) test1's average for all tests.

```
awk '{sum+=$4} END {for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) printf (Test%d %d\n", i-3, sum/NR)}'
```

I need to somehow increment the $4 to $5 and so on on each iteration to get what I want, although I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very possible!

Assuming the numerical columns start at column 4 and continue until the last column, also assuming the presence of a header row here (not clear if that's the case):

```
awk '
NR==1{ 
  for( i=4;i<=NF;i++) { 
    header[i] = $i 
  }; 
}
NR>1{ 
  for( i=4;i<=NF;i++) { 
    arr[i] += $i 
  }; 
}
END{ 
  print "column","avg";
  for( i=4;i<=NF;i++) { 
    print header[i],arr[i]/(NR-1) 
  };
}' data.txt
```

Sample input:

```
IDNum FirstName LastName test1Score test2Score test3Score
1     bob       jones    1          2          3
2     jill      jones    2          4          6
```

Sample output:

```
column avg
test1Score 1.5
test2Score 3
test3Score 4.5
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had read about the associative arrays, and was thinking that was gonna be necessary for this problem. but had not learned anything about them yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
awk 'NF>3 {for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) a[i]+=$i}
      END { for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) printf "Test%d %.2f\n", (i-3), (a[i]/NR)}'
```

Comment: what's the point of NF>3? Second, awk is associative array, it does not always export the report sequently

Comment: `NF>3` to make sure there are enough columns for computing averages (can be removed also). Yes it wont be sequential but can be made (editing).

Answer (score 2):

Using perl:

```
perl -lane 'if($.==1)
{
@a=@F[2..(scalar(@F)-1)] 
}
else
{
@a = map { $a[$_] + $F[$_+2] } 0..$#a;
}
END{for($i=0;$i<scalar(@a);$i++ ){print "Test".($i+1).":".$a[$i]/$.}}' your_file
```

Tested [Here](http://ideone.com/fYwNBO)